# Flutter: Position the textfield labelText

Tags: flutter

For the Flutter TextField LabelText, the default focused behaviour is as follow:

[image]

**...where the LabelText ("Email") is in the top border.**

I am trying to reposition the labelText as below when focused:

[image]

**...where the labelText is below the border.**

I know that a separate border can be made ontop of the textField, but then there is a bit more work involved to adopt the border behaviour based on the textField (ie. error, focused, disabled etc), and might cause more headache down the road.

Is there a way of moving the labelText position within the TextField properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually. Wrap TextField and GestureDetector->Container->Column->Text() * 2 into Stack widget .
in short, Stack has two widgets, TextField and GestureDector.
GestureDector has Contianer , Container has Column and Column as your desired Text widgets.

Comment: This is what I was hoping to avoid. As the Flutter gets updated, there is more chance of issues down the road. It doesn't seem like there is any native way of handling the LabelText position.

Comment: I would build a package for this. :)